# How to draw a contour plot using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, contour

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zeaa8ouwq3oo8c3/AAAgRNJwRL_TGwFWkBD6KFV0a?dl=0

My data: data.csv

I tried to draw a contour plot using Python.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
import time
import datetime

f = open("data.csv","r")
title = f.readline()
lines = f.readlines()
print len(lines)
xlist = []
ylist = []
zlist = []
for line in lines:
    titlecells = title.split(',')
    linecells = line.split(',')
    print len(titlecells)
    for i in range(1,len(titlecells)):
        items = titlecells[i].split('/')
        items = map(int, items)
        dt = datetime.datetime(items[0], items[1], items[2])
        sdt = datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)
        delta = int(str(dt - sdt).split(' ')[0]) / 10
        xlist.append(delta)
        ylist.append(linecells[0].replace('0~','').replace('m',''))
        try:
            zlist.append(float(linecells[i]))
        except ValueError:
            zlist.append(0)
print len(xlist)
print len(ylist)
print len(zlist)
ylist = map(int, ylist)

x = np.array(xlist)
y = np.array(ylist)
z = np.array(zlist)
print z
# Generate data: for N=1e6, the triangulation hogs 1 GB of memory
'''N = 1000000
x, y = 10 * np.random.random((2, N))
rho = np.sin(3*x) + np.cos(7*y)**3
print x.shape,y.shape'''
# Set up a regular grid of interpolation points
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 300), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 300)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
print xi,yi
# Interpolate; there's also method='cubic' for 2-D data such as here
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='linear')

plt.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
       extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Output obtained with Matlab: [image]

Input data: TKJS_20150903.xlsx

Matlab Code

```
clear all; close all;
% read data
list_d2 = dir('C:\\MATLAB_CODE\\Monitoring_well\\TS_Analysis\\MW\\data\\*.xlsx');

for k = 1:length(list_d2)
    station = list_d2(k).name(1:13);
    filename =  sprintf('C:\\MATLAB_CODE\\Monitoring_well\\TS_Analysis\\MW\\data\\%s.xlsx', station); 
    [MW_data, data_tex, alldata] = xlsread(filename,5);
    MW_data = MW_data(2:end,:);
    date = datenum(cellfun(@num2str,alldata(3:end,1),'UniformOutput', false),'yyyy/mm/dd');
    depth = cell2mat(alldata(2,2:end))';
    % MW_data=MW_data';

% compute gap between every rings
    for i = 1:length(MW_data(:,1))
        for j = 1:length(MW_data(1,:))-1
            disp(i,j) = MW_data(i,j)-MW_data(i,j+1);
        end
    end

    vel=disp';
%     dlmwrite('displacement.txt', disp, '\t');

    for i = 2:length(depth)-1
        thick(i) = depth(i+1)-depth(i);
    end
    thick=thick(1:end);
    thick1=repmat(thick,length(disp(:,1)),1);
%     dlmwrite('thickness.txt', thick, '\t');

% % check data
% figure(1);
% plot(MW_data,depth*(-1));

    % set well depth
    yg1 = 0; yg2 = 300;

    % make grid
    [xgrid,ygrid] = meshgrid(date(1):30:date(end),yg1:1:yg2);

    xint=repmat(date',length(thick),1);
    yint=repmat(depth(2:end),1,length(date));
    xint1 = reshape(xint, numel(xint), 1);
    yint1 = reshape(yint, numel(yint), 1);
    zint1 = reshape(vel, numel(vel), 1);

%     [Xwdp,Ywdp,Zwdp] = griddata(xint1,yint1,zint1,xgrid,ygrid);
    [Xwdp,Ywdp,Zwdp] = surfergriddata(xint1, yint1, zint1, xgrid, ygrid, 'kriging');

% save('cresult.mat');

    h1 = figure;
    set(h1,'paperorientation', 'portrait', 'color', [1 1 1], 'papertype','A4');
    set(gcf,'Units','Centimeter','Position', [5 5 18 20]);
    set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
    set(gca, 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight','bold');
    set(gca, 'FontName', 'Arial')
%     box on;

%     pcolor(xgrid, ygrid, Zwdp);

    surf(xgrid,ygrid,Zwdp); 
    shading interp;
    view(0,90);

    colorbar;
    z1=round(min(min(vel)));
    z2=round(max(max(vel)));
    caxis([z1 z2]);
%   caxis([-0.5 0.5]);
%   caxis([-1.2 1.2]);
%   caxis([-1 2]);
%   caxis([-1 8]);

%     x1=floor(min(min(date)));
%     x2=round(max(max(date)));
    axis([ min(min(date)), max(max(date)), 0, 300]);

        set(gca,'fontsize',5,'xticklabelmode','manual','yticklabelmode','manual');
    pa = get(gca,'xlim');
    pb = get(gca,'ylim');
    pa1 = (pa(1):pa(2));
    pa2 = (pb(1):pb(2));

    indx = find(mod(pa1-pa1(1),60)==0); 
    indy = find(mod(pa2,50)==0);
    set(gca,'xtick',pa1(indx),'xticklabel',[]);
    xrtime=get(gca,'xtick');
    xstime=datestr(xrtime,'yyyy/mm');

    for n=1:length(xrtime)
        text(xrtime(n),308,xstime(n,:),'HorizontalAlignment','center','fontsize',8,'fontweight','bold')
    end

    set(gca,'ytick',pa2(indy),'yticklabel',pa2(indy),'fontsize',8,'fontweight','bold');   
    set(gca,'YDir','reverse','tickdir','out'); hold on

%     gridnumy = zint1(:,1);
%     
%     for j = 1:length(gridnumy)
%             line(xgrid(1,:)',repmat(gridnumy(j),size(xgrid,2),1),'color','black','linestyle','-');
%     end

    well=list_d2(k).name(1:4)

    title({well 'Monitoring Well'}, 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight','bold');
    xlabel('Date', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight','bold');
    ylabel('Depth (m)', 'Fontsize', 12, 'FontWeight','bold');
%     clabel('Compression (cm)', 'Fontsize', 12, 'FontWeight','bold');

    list_p4=sprintf('C:\\MATLAB_CODE\\Monitoring_well\\TS_Analysis\\MW\\%s', well);
    print('-dpng','-r300', list_p4);

    clear MW_data data_tex xint xint1 yint yint1 zint1 thick thick1 vel disp

end
```

I want to get similar Output using Python.

But, I don't know how to improve my code.

Comment: What is your existing python code?

Comment: sorry  I forgot it.  thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, see my edit on how to include images properly (embed them, don't link them)

Comment: What output is matplotlib producing?

Comment: Nothing seems obviously wrong with the Python code. The output from Python looks reasonable, but it just doesn't match your matlab plot. Note that the matlab plot is focusing on a narrow range of dates. Also, I think that the data might be scaled somehow to provide more constant values over all depths.

Comment: I will put Matlab Code later. Please help me to rewrite Python code.

Comment: You can try my php implementation @ codeplex (https://cntm.codeplex.com/)